# Excel - how to look up a table for two values and return another value if these two values match

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, lookup

I hope I am explaining this clearly.

I have sample data 1, but I need this to automatically populate required sample data with the employee name

Sample data 1:

```
EmployeeName    Type         Result

A               Annual       Exceeds
B               Biennial     Warning
C               Biennial     DevelopmentNeeded
D               Biennial     PartiallyMeets
E               Annual       Meets
```

Required sample data: needed to provide an overall summary

```
          PartiallyMeets    Meets     Exceeds     DevelopmentNeeded     Warning 

Annual                                   A
Annual                        E
Annual
Biennial                                                                 B
Biennial                                                  C
Biennial          D
```

I've tried IFERROR, INDEX and MATCH combinations but I haven't had any success.

Appreciate any help you can provide!!
Thanks.

Comment: what happens if two employees have the same ranking in the same timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

I would think a PivotTable may solve your problem.

Step 1: 
Create a PivotTable.

Step 2:
Use Index - Match and Array formula to get the matching of the two 'criteria'.

Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqU9Z4LZATBedHdDVFpVcmVzU2JQWGtyajltakk5WWc&usp=sharing